# Read a Zip file and get the size of it in PHP

Tags: php, zip

I am trying to read and get the size of the zip file in PHP.

Following is my code:

```
    function create_zip($files, $file_name, $overwrite = false) {    
    foreach ($files as $imglink) {
        $img = file_get_contents($imglink);
        $destination_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'demoproject/downloads/' . time() . '.jpg';
        file_put_contents($destination_path, $img);
        $imgFiles[] = $destination_path;
    }

    if (file_exists($file_name) && !$overwrite) {
        return false;
    }
    $valid_files = array();
    if (is_array($imgFiles)) {
        foreach ($imgFiles as $file) {
            $valid_files[] = $file;
        }
    }

    if (count($valid_files)) {
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        if ($zip->open($file_name, $overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
            echo "Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
        }
        foreach ($valid_files as $file) {
            $zip->addFile($file, pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_BASENAME));
        }

        $count = $zip->numFiles;
        $resultArr = array();
        $resultArr['count'] = $count;
        $resultArr['destination'] = $file_name;

        $filename = $file_name;
        $filepath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'demoproject/';


        $fileSize = filesize($filepath . $filename) / 1024;

        echo 'size of the file is : ' . $fileSize . ' kb';
        exit;

//        $size = 0;
//        $resource = zip_open($filepath . $filename);
//        while ($dir_resource = zip_read($resource)) {
//            $size += zip_entry_filesize($dir_resource);
//        }

        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "\"");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Length: " . zip_entry_filesize($filepath . $filename));

        if (@readfile($filepath . $filename) === false) {
            header('http://localhost/demoproject/fbindex.php');
            return 500;
        } else {
            header('Location:http://localhost/demoproject/fbindex.php');
            return 200;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

`$files` : contain the array of images and

`$file_name` : contain name of file : that is : `$file_name = time() . ".zip";`

In the above code `$filename` contains the actual zip file and `$filepath` contains the location of the zip file.

The issue is it's reading the file but always showing its size 0 instead of actual file size.

This is I am doing :

`echo $size;`

`O/P : 0`

Where am I going wrong? Need Help. Thanks

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` gives `var/www` etc. and not ends with `/`. Try `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/demoproject/'`.

Comment: No but its giving me : `D:/wamp/www/demoproject/1357553314.zip`. So is it ok?

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
$fileSize =  filesize($filepath . $filename)/1024;
echo 'size of the file is : '.$fileSize.' kb';
```

Comment: This is also not working.  output : `size of the file is : 0 kb`

Comment: Here is my path along with filename : `D:/wamp/www/demoproject/1357556559.zip`

Comment: Your filesize returns `false` so there is an error, that explains your `0` add `error_reporting(E_WARN)` above `$fileSize`

Comment: check it - 
if file_exists ($filepath.$filename){
$fileSize =  filesize($filepath . $filename)/1024;
echo 'size of the file is : '.$fileSize.' kb';
}

Comment: it is not going under `if` condition

Comment: that means your zip is not created yet in the specified location.

Comment: i think you have done a mistake here. put a "/" before "demoproject" -
**$filepath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'demoproject/';**

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you [close](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.close.php) ZIP file just after adding files to it?

```
$zip->close();
```

Comment: I added...but problem is still persist

Answer (score 0):

Try `clearstatcache()` just before calling `filesize()`.

Closing your zip file before all this is also a great idea.

I know I'm a bit late on this, but who knows?